# How do I get more Palico tickets?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

I've gotten a Palico ticket from my Palico twice now, I don't know what triggers the unlock of such a ticket, but I certainly need more.

What do I need to do to get more of these tickets?Do quests? Level my Palico to specific levels? Or is it just random?

Comment: I haven't counted them but I just get them periodically after doing quests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's from you bonding with your main Palico the only way you can during the game: By completing quests and expeditions. If you look at the description of the ticket you'll find:

> Proof of you and your Felyne Palicoes' rapport. Collect enough and it
>   might pay off.

It will help if you keep your main Palico Enthused by eating before every quest/expedition and though I haven't completely confirmed it yet it seems the more higher tier quests you do the faster you get them. I've got way more once I started to do high rank missions.

Comment: What extra value does that link add? I'm confused as to how it's helping. The answer is good, although I'd like more details (How many quests are needed, how much influence does eating have, ...)

Comment: @Arperum It was in case someone didn't know the definition of rapport which can be removed. I wish I had a more definite answer, but I couldn't tell you the exact amount of quests needed to get a ticket. When I was doing low rank, I got one every 15 - 25 missions. Now that I'm doing high rank it's more like 10 - 20.

Comment: OK, I'll remove the link and I'll wait for a bit hoping that someone can enlighten us more about the mechanic :)